# TinyMCE plugin to save with cancel button

Tags: javascript, plugin, callback, text-editor

Please provide constructive criticism for this TinyMCE plugin which allows the user to save the content, or cancel and go back to the original.

[JS Bin](http://output.jsbin.com/bozojo)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            tinymce._addHTML=function(id,html){
                //Is there a better way to do this?
                var e=this.get(id);
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=html;
                e.startContent = html;
                e.setContent(html);
                //e.save(); //Remove??
            }
            tinymce.PluginManager.add('mysave', function(editor) {

                function save() {
                    var formObj;

                    formObj = tinymce.DOM.getParent(editor.id, 'form');

                    if (editor.getParam('mysave_enablewhendirty', true) && !editor.isDirty()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    editor.startContent = editor.getContent();
                    editor.hide();

                    //tinymce.triggerSave();
                    editor.save();

                    if (editor.getParam('mysave_onsavecallback')) {
                        editor.execCallback('mysave_onsavecallback', editor);
                        editor.nodeChanged();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (formObj) {
                        editor.setDirty(false);

                        if (!formObj.onsubmit || formObj.onsubmit()) {
                            if (typeof formObj.submit == 'function') {
                                formObj.submit();
                            } else {
                                displayErrorMessage(editor.translate('Error: Form submit field collision.'));
                            }
                        }

                        editor.nodeChanged();
                    } else {
                        displayErrorMessage(editor.translate('Error: No form element found.'));
                    }
                }

                function displayErrorMessage(message) {
                    editor.notificationManager.open({
                        text: message,
                        type: 'error'
                    });
                }

                function cancel() {
                    if (editor.getParam('mysave_oncancelconfirmcallback') && editor.isDirty()) {
                        editor.execCallback('mysave_oncancelconfirmcallback', editor, cancelChanges);
                    } else {
                        cancelChanges();
                    }

                    function cancelChanges() {
                        var h = tinymce.trim(editor.startContent);

                        if (editor.getParam('mysave_oncancelcallback')) {
                            editor.execCallback('mysave_oncancelcallback', editor);
                        }

                        editor.setContent(h);
                        editor.undoManager.clear();
                        editor.nodeChanged();

                        //tinymce.triggerSave();
                        editor.save();
                        editor.setDirty(false);

                        editor.hide();
                    }

                    stateToggle.call(mySaveButton);
                    mySaveButton.disabled(true);
                }

                function stateToggle() {
                    var self = this;
                    editor.on('nodeChange dirty', function() {
                        self.disabled(editor.getParam('mysave_enablewhendirty', true) && !editor.isDirty());
                    });
                }

                editor.addCommand('mceMySave', save);
                editor.addCommand('mceMyCancel', cancel);

                var mySaveButton;
                editor.addButton('mysave', {
                    icon: 'save',
                    text: 'Save',
                    title: 'Save changes and close editor',
                    cmd: 'mceMySave',
                    disabled: true,
                    onPostRender: function() {
                        mySaveButton = this;
                        stateToggle.call(this);
                    }
                });

                editor.addButton('mycancel', {
                    icon: 'remove',
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    title: 'Cancel changes and close editor',
                    cmd: 'mceMyCancel',
                    disabled: false
                });

                editor.addShortcut('Meta+S', '', 'mceMySave');

            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #box {
                border: 1px solid;
            }
            .section {
                padding:10px; height:200px;width:800px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            tinymce.init({
                selector: '.content',
                width : 800,
                height: 100,
                toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough fontsizeselect | bullist numlist | link | mysave mycancel',
                plugins: 'spellchecker link paste mysave',
                //external_plugins: {"mysave": "/path/to/tinymce/plugin.js"},
                browser_spellcheck: true,
                save_enablewhendirty: true, // Enabled by default
                mysave_oncancelconfirmcallback: function(editor, confirmedCallback) {
                    if (confirm('You have unsaved work. Are you sure you want to cancel?')) {
                        console.log('cancelled');
                        confirmedCallback();
                    } else {
                        console.log('cancel cancelled');
                    }
                },
                mysave_oncancelcallback : function(editor) {
                    console.log('cancel callback');
                },
                mysave_onsavecallback: function (editor) {
                    console.log('saved');
                },
                menubar: false,
                statusbar: false,
                setup: function(ed) {
                    ed.on('init', function(e) {
                        e.target.hide();
                    });
                }
            });
            $(function() {

                $("#open").click(function(){$("#dialog").dialog("open");});
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen    : false,
                    resizable   : false,
                    height      : 800,
                    width       : 800, 
                    modal       : true,
                    open        : function() {
                        tinymce._addHTML('content1','New text 1 from DB.');
                        tinymce._addHTML('content2','New text 2 from DB.');
                        tinymce._addHTML('content3','New text 3 from DB.');
                        //$('#content1').html('New text 1 from DB.');
                        //tinymce.get('content1').startContent = 'New text 1 from DB.';
                        //tinymce.get('content1').setContent("Newer text 1 from DB.");
                        //tinymce.get('content1').save();
                        //tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('Newest text 1 from DB.');
                    }
                });

                $('a.edit').click(function() {
                    tinymce.get($(this).closest('div.section').find('div.content').attr('id')).show();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id='open'>Open</button>
        <div id="dialog" title="dialog title">
            <div id="box">
                <div class="section">
                    <p>Content 1 <a href="#" class="edit" id="edit1">edit</a></p>
                    <div id="content1" class="content">Original text 1.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <p>Content 2 <a href="#" class="edit" id="edit2">edit</a></p>
                    <div id="content2" class="content">Original text 2.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <p>Content 3 <a href="#" class="edit" id="edit3">edit</a></p>
                    <div id="content3" class="content">Original text 3.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```